# Watson Assistant queries

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant-solutions

I would like to Know if it was possible, when called the Cloud Function for the query on Watson Assistant, to return more results than the deafult ones (10 results).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you want to return more than 10 intents? If so this is not possible.